# Python Skeleton Generator

Tags: python, jetbrains-ide

While doing programming in Python I found Skeleton generator running before the start of any program. I tried to figure out but couldn't find the right answer of it. I want to know the exact purpose of Skeleton generator in Python.

Comment: Are you talking about the [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) IDE? According to their Github repository, _[Python skeletons are Python files that contain API definitions of existing libraries extended for static analysis tools.](https://github.com/JetBrains/python-skeletons)_. The IDE uses these files to provide features such as for type hits, intelligent code-completion, code navigation, tooltips/help about the standdard Python libraries, etc.

Comment: Its PyCharm IDE. Problem resolved. Thanks.